# NestJS - Consume EventPattern only if header variable has specific value

Tags: typescript, events, apache-kafka, nestjs

I have a project made with NestJS.
I am using a Kafka server to emit events and NestJS to consume them.
I need to create a consumer with the topic `my-topic` that is called only when the variable `my-header-variable` in the header has a specific value.

I have to do something like this

```js
@MyEventPattern('my-pattern', { 'my-header-variable': 'secret'})
function index(@Payload() data: any) {
 // ... Do it only if 'my-header-variable' == 'secret'
}
```

How can I create this behavior?
Is there something already written?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something that works but is not the complete answer

```js
@EventPattern('my-pattern')
@AdditionalDecorator()
function index(@Payload() data: any) {
 // ... Do it only if 'my-header-variable' == 'secret'
}
```

In This solution I created an additional decorator that works with `@EventPattern` and return `undefined` if the header is not what expected.
This is the decorator.

```js
export const AdditionalDecorator = () => {
   return (target: any, methodName: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = function (data: any, context: KafkaContext) {
      const { headers } = context.getMessage();
      if (!headers || headers['my-header-variable'] !== 'secret') return undefined;      
      return originalMethod.call(this, data, context);
    };

    return descriptor;
  };
};
```

It works but I am still looking for a REAL solution.